# Azure CLI parsing

Tags: bash, azure, command-line-interface

I am using Azure CLI 2.0 in a bash script and I am trying to retrieve my keys for a storage account. I need to put the data in a variable and store key1 in a ENV variable. How can I do this properly? I am not sure on the parsing of the output, the assigning variable and CLI call I got fine.

I thought about doing a grep search but that won't work well since the keys change (I think they do anyways)

`az storage account keys list --account-name acc_name --resource-group default-rg --output table`

**Output**

```
KeyName    Permissions    Value
---------  -------------  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
key1       Full           KEY1VALUE
key2       Full           KEY2VALUE
```

Comment: @Nic3500 I am pretty sure they change weekly so sadly a grep wouldn't work. If a basic grep did I would just hardcode the keys in since there is not much security in the commands needed to get the value.

For the second idea, can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: Please check my answer, it was too long for a comment.  I have never experienced a key changing, but I have not worked on Azure for a couple months, I am not certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I did it, in a bash script:

```
sakey=$($az storage account keys list --account-name $sa --resource-group $rg | grep value | head -1 | cut -d'"' -f4)
```

$az: azure command, with path
$sa: storage account name
$rg: resource group name

This can be run in a script, as often as you need.  The 1st key will be stored in variable $sakey.  I did not put option "--output table" so the parsing is easier to do with `grep`, `head` and `cut`.

Comment: Thanks I just figured it out, I was using the output table instead of the JSON object that it outputs without the table part. I know how to parse this now. Marked you as correct.

Comment: I was informed that the command `jq` would be better for parsing JSON, but I had this already done.

Comment: Yeah that is the route I went when I said I figured it out. I had used the `jq` and `tr` commands before to parse JSON, you removing the `--output table` was the biggest help.